# Does the swift compiler/linker automatically remove unused methods/classes/extensions, etc.?

Tags: swift, optimization, compiler-optimization

We have a lot of code which is usable in any iOS application we write. Things such as:

- Custom/Common Controls
- Extensions on common objects like UIView, UIImage and UIViewController
- Global utility functions
- Global constants
- Related sets of files that make up common 'features' like a picker screen that can be used with anything that can be enumerated.

For reasons unrelated to this question, we cannot use static or dynamic libraries. These must be included in the project as actual source files.

There are several hundred of these 'core' files so what I've been doing is adding all the files to the project (referencing a shared location on disk), but only adding them to specific targets as they are used/needed.

The problem is this becomes quite tedious to do, especially when there are sets of related files which all reference others. Tracking them down one by one is a real pain!

What I'm wondering is if I can simply include everything in the target, then count on the compiler to remove all the unused code.

For instance, I have several extension methods on UIView.  If I don't use them in a particular target, will the compiler exclude that code from the compiled binary, or will it be compiled in, unreachable, bloating the code size for no reason?

Comment: How would the compiler know that a method is unused? You could call `performSelector` with a string set at runtime - that could call any method in your app.

Comment: Have you tried it with optimizations on?

Comment: Yeah, @Ashley, that's what I was thinking/worried about.  I was hoping there was an optimization that would remove them all anyway.

Comment: @Fabian, that's actually what I'm asking... what optimizations and such I can turn on.  I'm an expert at Swift, but still pretty new around the compiler, etc.  That's usually handled by a different team.

Comment: How would the optimiser know to remove them if it can't know if they're called or not?

Comment: As I just said, I was hoping they would be removed anyway.  We generally don't call things by a string selector, and if we did/needed to, I was wondering if you could mark-up/attribute a method saying 'Don't remove this!' like you can in other languages.

Comment: Setting `Whole Module Optimization` (Xcode9, the setting changed in Xcode10) might help you with this, as with this setting the compiler bundles all swift files into an enormous one, thus has more chances in finding unused stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Dead functions

The compiler's SILOptimizer [has a dead function elimination pass](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/SILOptimizer/IPO/DeadFunctionElimination.cpp), which eliminates functions and methods that are known not to be called (along with any associated vtable/witness table entries).

To fully take advantage of this, you'll want to be using [whole module optimisation](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/) (`-wmo`) in order to ensure that the compiler can analyse whether `internal` functions are called or not from within the same module.

You can quite easily test this out for yourself, for example using the following code:

```
class C {}
extension C {
  @inline(never) func foo() {}
  @inline(never) func bar() {}
}

@inline(never) func foo() {}
@inline(never) func bar() {}
bar()

let c = C()
c.bar()
```

<sup>(I'm using the unofficial `@inline(never)` here to ensure the functions aren't optimised away by inlining)</sup>

If we run `xcrun swiftc -emit-sil -O -wmo main.swift | xcrun swift-demangle`, we can see the generated SIL:

```
sil_stage canonical

import Builtin
import Swift
import SwiftShims

class C {
  init()
  deinit
}

extension C {
  @inline(never) func foo()
  @inline(never) func bar()
}

@inline(never) func foo()

@inline(never) func bar()

let c: C

// c
sil_global hidden [let] @main.c : main.C : $C

// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  // function_ref bar()
  %2 = function_ref @main.bar() -> () : $@convention(thin) () -> () // user: %3
  %3 = apply %2() : $@convention(thin) () -> ()
  alloc_global @main.c : main.C                  // id: %4
  %5 = global_addr @main.c : main.C : $*C        // user: %8
  %6 = alloc_ref $C                               // users: %8, %7
  debug_value %6 : $C, let, name "self", argno 1  // id: %7
  store %6 to %5 : $*C                            // id: %8
  // function_ref specialized C.bar()
  %9 = function_ref @function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of main.C.bar() -> () : $@convention(thin) () -> () // user: %10
  %10 = apply %9() : $@convention(thin) () -> ()
  %11 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0         // user: %12
  %12 = struct $Int32 (%11 : $Builtin.Int32)      // user: %13
  return %12 : $Int32                             // id: %13
} // end sil function 'main'

// C.__deallocating_deinit
sil hidden @main.C.__deallocating_deinit : $@convention(method) (@owned C) -> () {
// %0                                             // users: %3, %2, %1
bb0(%0 : $C):
  debug_value %0 : $C, let, name "self", argno 1  // id: %1
  debug_value %0 : $C, let, name "self", argno 1  // id: %2
  dealloc_ref %0 : $C                             // id: %3
  %4 = tuple ()                                   // user: %5
  return %4 : $()                                 // id: %5
} // end sil function 'main.C.__deallocating_deinit'

// bar()
sil hidden [noinline] @main.bar() -> () : $@convention(thin) () -> () {
bb0:
  %0 = tuple ()                                   // user: %1
  return %0 : $()                                 // id: %1
} // end sil function 'main.bar() -> ()'

// specialized C.bar()
sil shared [noinline] @function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of main.C.bar() -> () : $@convention(thin) () -> () {
bb0:
  %0 = tuple ()                                   // user: %1
  return %0 : $()                                 // id: %1
} // end sil function 'function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of main.C.bar() -> ()'

sil_vtable C {
  #C.deinit!deallocator: @main.C.__deallocating_deinit  // C.__deallocating_deinit
}
```

You'll note that only the `bar` function and method have had their bodies emitted (near the bottom). While there are still definitions for `foo` at the top of the SIL, they get removed as the SIL is lowered to LLVM IR.

> I was wondering if you could mark-up/attribute a method saying 'Don't remove this!' like you can in other languages

There isn't currently an official attribute for this, but there is an underscored `@_optimize(none)` attribute which tells the optimiser not to touch something:

```
@_optimize(none) func foo() {}
```

Though given the attribute is underscored, use at your own risk.

---

#### Dead type metadata

Unfortunately, the compiler currently (as of Swift 4.2) doesn't *appear* to have an optimisation pass that eliminates the associated metadata for types that are known to not be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think "WBBldes" will help you.What you want is removing the code that you never use. WBBlades is the tool that can detect Swift & Objective-C unused code. https://github.com/wuba/WBBlades